# Sometimes I'd like to know what my shells aliases/functions are before I execute them. Can I log them without executing them?

Tags: shell

I'm not sure if this is a stupid question but I'll often run into the sinario were I don't know what my commands are set to are without having to open my `.zshrc` (I'm using zsh obviously).

For instance lets use `gs`. I'm not sure which of the following `gs` will execute:

`alias gs="git status"`

or `alias gs="gulp serve"`

or `alias gs="grunt serve"`

Is there a command, or something like `echo gs`, `"$(gs)"` or `echo "$(gs)"` that will log the command (e.g. `git status`) rather executing what ever I have `gs` set to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the `alias` command to print out all of your shell aliases. If you want to know what a particular alias resolves to, just pass it to the `alias` command as an argument:

```
➜  alias gs
gs='git status'
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you. Can you also do this with functions?

Comment: Yes, for that you can use the `functions` command and pass the name of the function: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166609/how-to-print-the-code-of-a-shell-function-in-terminal. Note that `zsh` will also do tab completion of functions you've declared in `.zshrc` if you type the first few letters.

Comment: @Vyga would you mind marking my answer correct if it gave you what you needed?

Comment: sorry, it was making me wait 8 min to do so yesterday. Thanks again cheers